# Handle communication in multi layer application

Tags: python, communication, observer-pattern

I am creating an application using Python.

I first designed an API, that is working fine. 
I am now designing my GUI. The GUI starts a Thread that is used to perform tasks against the API.

Up to now, I used the Observer pattern to handle communication through the different layers.
Basically, communication can be of two types (mainly):
- The GUI asking the Thread (and the API subsequently) to START/STOP
- The API giving information back to the Thread, that propagates to the GUI.

Here is a simple schema of the current architecture I am talking about. 
One arrow means "notify", basically.

[image: Current Observer/Observable communication]

My concern is that when the application Thread communicates, both the Gui and the API receive the message because they subscribed. Thing is, each message is only meant to be read by one of the two.

What I did to solve that is to send an message together with an ID. Each of the three elements have an id and they know whether the message is for them or now. 
But I am not sure if this is the "correct" (understand nicest) way to do it. What if I have more parties in the future ?

I started thinking about some kind of manager handling communication, but It would then have to be at the top of the architecture, and I am not sure how to further organize it :s.

I am not asking for a complete solution, but mainly ideas or best practises by more experienced people ;)

I can keep handling multiple Observer pattern in this simple case.
But I was thinking about porting my code on a server. In this case, I am likely to have way more than one thread for the application, and handling API calls will become quite impossible.

Link to the code I am talking about : 
[GUI](https://github.com/jlengrand/FaceMovie/blob/gui_v2/ivolution/gui_wx/IvolutionWindow.py), [ApplicationThread](https://github.com/jlengrand/FaceMovie/blob/gui_v2/ivolution/FacemovieThread.py) and [Application API](https://github.com/jlengrand/FaceMovie/blob/gui_v2/ivolution/Facemovie_lib.py).

You want to look at notify and update methods.

Thx for any piece of advice !

Comment: What exactly are you using to implement the communication from the Application Thread?

Comment: I use an Observer/Observable pattern I coded myself, that sends a list of strings. The first string is the id of the object I want to talk to, the rest my message. Was that your question ?

Comment: I was just trying to understand the needed paths of communication. If the Application Thread is simply acting as a broken between the other two, why wouldn't you just use discreet connections between GUI/Thread and Thread/Api ?

Comment: If that helps you, I added a link to the full code. I don't exactly understand what you mean by discreet connections. You mean bypassing the middle thread ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the nice implementation of the observer pattern I've met is the signal/slot system in Qt. Objects have signals, and slots (which are actually methods) can be connected to signals. The connected slots are called when the signals are emitted.

It seems to me that some of your problems may stem from the fact you have single communication canal in each of your objects. This forces you to have some dispatch mechanism in every `update` method, and makes the code quite complex.

Taking inspiration from Qt, you could have different signals for each kind of message and recipient. The code for signal would look like :

```
class Signal:
    def __init__(self):
        self.subs = []

    def subscribe(self, s):
        self.subs.append(s)

    def signal(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for s in self.subs:
            s(*args, **kwargs)
```

---

For example, the gui would have a signal `stop_signal` and the thread a method to handle it :

```
def handle_gui_stop(self):
    self.console_logger.debug("Facemovie is going to stop")
    self.my_logger.debug("Facemovie is going to stop")
    self.stop_process = True
    # ...
```

Somewhere in the initialization code, we would tie everything together :

```
gui.stop_signal.subscribe(thread.handle_gui_stop)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I think you got the root of my problem, and your solution seems nice. I have actually been working on a very similar solution lately, using json objects instead of your signal class (it would make it easier to create a web interface for example). What I still really wonder about is who should be aware of who. I think it is saner if the GUI knows as few as possible about the core. But in this case the solution might be to build a proper API with the corresponding signals. 
I have to think about that further :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently created a GUI app with similar architecture (GUI thread + a separate work thread), and I end up creating an explicit protocol between threads, in a form of two queues (from Queue Python module). One queue is for requests made by GUI and is consumed by worker thread(s). The other queue is for answers produces by worker threads and consumed by GUI.

I find it much clearer when communication between threads is explicit, you have full control over when and where the updating is done (GUI methods can be called only from the GUI thread).

A natural extension of this model in a server environment is a message queue protocol like AMQP.

Comment: Thx for answer, and keyword :). Thing is, communication is nt really my problem. My issue here is that I have three layers, and the GUI needs data from both the others. I am not sure whether the GUI should really know about the fact that there are two layers. So my messages go through the middle layer.
Would your solution mean that I should handle the communication between each layer with different technologies?

Comment: What are your layers? I see GUI and API. The thread is not a layer, if it calls API only. Don't confuse modules (layers) with runtime components using modules (threads). Also "communication is not a problem" is a controversial statement in a multi-threaded GUI application, because it matters a lot when and in which thread code is executed. Generally, I would advise creating a "service layer" (or "facade") to be used by GUI (so GUI knows about this service layer only, not about all modules in an application). And as I wrote I found explicit inter-thread communication to work best in a GUI app.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. What I called thread is actually really a layer. I called it thread because it runs as a thread, started by the GUI. I does use the API. Actually, the Thread uses API calls to perform operations the GUI asked. But it is more clever than just calling one API method. Basically, I think it is what you call the service layer. 
But some of the messages that come from the API are useful for the GUI itself (mostly for user information); and I want the GUI to see them. This explains the current architecture I got

Answer (score 2):

Application thread must be more explicit about communications since it's the communicator between GUI and Application API. This may be achieved by separating working sets (queues) coming from GUI and from Application API. Also, Application Thread must be able to handle delivery-type of pattern, which includes command senders and recipients. This includes managing communications between different queues (e.g. GUI queue has pending command which is awaiting for the command in the Application API queue. Once this one completes, then the Application Thread passes results back between the queues). And each queue is the observer itself.

In terms of extending the application, it seems to me that you want to add more GUIs in the future, which will be handled by request/response (or sender/receiver) pattern implementation described above (that will suffice).

If you plan to add more layers *vertically* instead of *horisontally* then you should not use the same Application Thread to communicate upper between new layers. Well, physically it can be the same, but virtually it must be different at least. This can be achieved by exactly implementing what I described above again (separate queues). By introducing dynamically adding queues you will open the possibility to add a new layer (new layer simply corresponds to new queue then).

Comment: Thx for the answer. You are the second one to talk about Queues. This may be the word I am searching for after all.
And you are right, my future aim is to add GUIs. To be a bit more precise, I used the current GUI as a dev tool, and a first version. My final aim is to go in the cloud and use a web interface. 
But are Python Queues compatible with other technologies?

Comment: I cannot consult about Python queue implementation specifics. However, think about a queue just like a queue of tasks (commands), and here it will become compatible with any other platform. e.g. App Thread layer's App API-specific queue receives a task from App API, then App Thread registers another task in the queue specific to other technology (such as MS BizTalk-specific queue) and awaits for its completion as described before. However, the task is still in Python tier but connects the entire system with BizTalk tier. And here it became integrated with BizTalk! I think this answers your Q.

Comment: It does give me some bizzwords that will definitely be helpful when multiple clients will access the server at the same time. I really like the idea of message queue
I am not sure the fundamentals of your solution is really different of mine (or the one of the others) tough.
The idea is basically to use the same communication technology, but to a channel to point to. I think it is what I am going to do.

Comment: I just read the answer of Radomir Liksy and that seems something similar. One thing which I agree with him and you need to notice is, GUI must know about existence of APP API. But key point to add here is, GUI does not physically use APP API. You'd ask "How these two together?". Here's how: design GUI with APP API in mind, make layer models communicate. Next, abstract away the communication implementation and introduce APP Thread layer, which would be message-based implementation of the communication abstractions. This gives benefit to optimize/replace communication semantics in the future.

Comment: Wow, I'd love to discuss about that around a coffee :). Something SO is still not capable to do. Thanks for the complete answers though, I'll try to make the best out of it

Answer (score 0):

Specially with GUIs, I recomend another pattern: [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). It includes the Observer patterns in it and is more robust than the Observer alone.

It solves your concern because it separates concerns: each layer has a very specific role and you can change any of them, as long as you don't change the interface between them.